# Kann „Tandem“ als weiblich bzw. männlich betrachtet werden?

Tags: gender

Nehmen wir an, Herr Mustermann macht eine Tandempartnerschaft ab. Er kann wohl sagen

> Mustermann: „Heute treffe ich *meine Tandempartnerin.*“

bzw.

> Mustermann: „Heute treffe ich *meinen Tandempartner.*“

Es ist trotzdem fragwürdig, ob das Ganze wirklich geläufig ist. Ich ahne, man kürzt die Nomina *Tandempartnerin* und *Tandempartner* auf *Tandem* ab. Wenn das richtig wäre, wäre es verständlich, wenn man sagt

> „Heute treffe ich *meine(n)* Tandem“ ?

D.h. da *Tandem* sächlich ist, soll ich mich für die Semantik oder für die Syntax entscheiden? Geht beides?

**EDIT:** Nachdem ich die Antworten gelesen habe, finde ich, dass ich wenigstens den Ursprung der Frage erklären sollte. Das lässt sich am besten durch ein Beispiel erklären, und zwar sagt man

> Ich hätte gerne ein Franziskaner!

und nicht *einen Franziskaner*, selbst wenn das Nomen *Franziskaner* männlich ist. Das Nomen hat ja schon da seine ursprüngliche Bedeutung verloren und *Franziskaner* stellt eher Bier dar, welches sächlich ist. Ich dachte *Tandem* (das Fahrrad) wäre ein bildhafter Ursprung des Tandemsystems – weil da zwei den gleichen Zweck haben, nämlich fahren. Und dass sich deswegen *Tandem* irgendwie auf die Person, mit der man die Tandempartnerschaft macht, beziehen könnte.

Comment: Für mich ist ein Tandem ein Fahrrad. Die anderen Definition waren mir nicht geläufig. Ich denke, dass geht auch anderen Muttersprachler so. Ich würde also vorschlagen, nicht davon auszugehen, dass dich irgendjemand versteht, ob mit oder richtigem Geschlecht. Unabhängig davon, ich würde es als OK betrachten, ob es gängig ist (unter Kennern), weiß ich nicht; ob es richtig wäre, bezweifle ich.

Comment: Definitiv immer sächlich. Meine(n) Tandem klingt für mich falsch. Das sage ich als Kenner :)

Comment: Mit dem Edit ist die Frage absolut nachvollziehbar :) Allerdings gibt es hier einen wichtigen Unterschied: "Franziskaner" (Achtung: mit "z") ist in diesem Fall ein Marken-/Eigenname und somit eigentlich nicht mit dem Tandem-Beispiel vergleichbar.

Comment: Falls Du glaubst, Tandem sei sächlich, weil Fahrrad sächlich ist, so liegst Du falsch. Solche Ableitungen gibt es nicht, und funktionieren auch nicht, wie man am Tandemsprung (m.) sieht.

Comment: Sollte man vielleicht den tag [tag:compounds] hinzufügen?

Comment: Du kannst doch nicht behaupten Tandem sei eine Abkürzung, wenn Du einen Wortbestandteil unter den Tisch fallen lässt! Ein Wein ist ja auch keine Abkürzung für ein Weinglas. Oder ein Rat ist keine Abkürzung für Rathaus.

Comment: @userunknown ja da hast du recht. Den genauen Begriff kenne ich leider nicht, und da die Frage schon beantwortet wurde und ich meinen Kommentar nicht korrigieren kann, es ist ok. (Vielleicht hätte ich einfach *kurze Form* o.ä. wählen sollen, weiß ich nicht).

Comment: Ist das denn ein Ausdruck der tatsächlich als Kürzel so wie dargestellt für die Personen von einer größeren Gruppe Sprecher/Hörer benutzt und verstanden wird? Ist es vielleicht auch importierter Sprachgebrauch, konkret: Sagt man das auf Englisch so? Es erinnert mich nämlich an einen häßlichen Sprachgebrauch mancher Programmierer bei einem Fachwort: Der JITTER - eine selbstproduzierte Abkürzung für Just-in-Time-Compiler. M.E. hat da jmd. JIT und Jitter zusammengeschmissen und nicht gemerkt, dass das nichts miteinander zu tun hat.

Comment: Man sagt "ein Franziskaner", weil es der Name eines Biers ist: man will "ein [Franziskaner-] Bier". Analog mit Zeitungen: "die [Zeitung] Weltbild".

Comment: Ich bin aus Wien. Wenn man bei mir zuhause einen (nicht "ein"!) Franziskaner bestellt, bekommt man kein Bier sondern einen Kaffee (eine helle Melange mit Schlagobers in einem Glas)

Comment: @Robert: Gerade wenn das "Bier" weggelassen wird kann man nicht feststellen, was weggelassen wurde. Da es keine verbindliche Absprache gibt, wie man ermittelt, was weggelassen wurde kann es ebensogut ein anderer Begriff sein, der zufällig ein anderes Geschlecht hat - das Bier, die Flüssigkeit, der Trunk?

Comment: @user unknown Da musst Du Dich aber sprachlich ganz schön verrenken, wenn Du Dein Bier als Trunk oder gar Flüssigkeit bestellst... Es ergibt sich aus dem Kontext, dass Franziskaner ein Bier (kein Mönch oder Kaffee) ist.

Comment: @Robert: Wieso? Welche Verrenkung ist dazu nötig? Ich hätte auch noch "Die Erfrischung", "Die Stärkung" und "Die Anregung" zu bieten.

Comment: @user unknown und woher soll der Kellner wissen, welche Erischung, Anregung oder Stärkung Du willst? Langsam wird's albern...

Comment: @Robert: Aus dem Kontext ergibt sich meistens nicht dass Franziskaner ein Bier ist, denn in einer Kneipe kann man in der Regel auch Cola, Wein und Schnaps bestellen. Es ist vielmehr so, dass die Beteiligten das Wissen, was ein Franziskaner ist, schon mitbringen. Das Franziskaner wird aber gerade nicht abhängig vom Kontext sein Geschlecht wechseln können, womit belegt ist, dass Du falsch liegen musst.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ein Tandem ist ein Fahrrad für zwei Personen und es ist sächlich:

> **Das** Tandem.

Andere Definitionen, die alle vom zweisitzigen Fahrrad abgeleitet sind, findet man hier: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem aber in jedem Fall ist das Tandem sächlich.

Ich konnte aber keine Definition für »Tandem« finden, bei der eine Person als »Tandem« bezeichnet wird. Der Satz

```
Heute treffe ich mein Tandem.
```

wäre grammatisch zwar so, wie er da steht, korrekt (*mein*, weil *das* Tandem sächlich ist), ist aber ebenso sinnvoll wie »Heute treffe ich meinen linken Schuh« oder »Heute treffe ich meinen Suppenlöffel«.

---

### Genus von Komposita

Eine ganz andere Frage ist die Frage nach dem Geschlecht zusammengesetzter Wörter. Sie ist ganz einfach zu beantworten:

**Das grammatikalische Geschlecht (das Genus) eines Kompositums (zusammengesetzten Substantivs) ist *IMMER* das Geschlecht des letzten Bestandteils.**
Von dieser Regel gibt es keine Ausnahmen!

Also:

> »**Der** Tandempartner«, weil **der** Partner männlich ist.
>   »**Die** Tandempartnerin«, weil **die** Partnerin weiblich ist.

Andere Beispiele:

> **Das** Dampfschiff (der Dampf, **das** Schiff)
>   **Das** Donaudampfschiff (die Donau, der Dampf, **das** Schiff)
>   **Die** Donaudampfschifffahrt (die Donau, der Dampf, **die** Schifffahrt)
>   **Die** Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaft (die Donau, der Dampf, die Schifffahrt, **die** Gesellschaft)
>   **Der** Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän ([…], **der** Kapitän)

Answer (score 4):

Tandem ist wirklich sächlich und bezeichnet, wenn nicht ein Fahrrad, dann die Gemeinschaft der beiden. *Tandempartner* oder *Tandempartnerin* würde man auch umgangssprachlich sagen.

Answer (score 1):

Die ersten zwei Möglichkeiten sind richtig.

Als dritte Möglichkeit würde ich "mein Tandem" vorschlagen, was aber mit dem Fahhradtypus verwechselt werden könnte, wie @Em1 festgestellt hat.